# Two processes sharing same pcap file

Tags: c++, linux, process, parallel-processing

I have a c++ program (executing on linux) which makes use of a pcap file. Each packet from this pcap file is processed and results are generated in a text file. I have written a script that run two instances of this program with different input arguments . One instance of this program runs on one CPU and the other instance runs on second CPU.

The problem is that in my program I have hard coded the pcap file name. As a result, on both CPUs the pcap file is opened and packets are read from it.

I want that instead both of the programs open up the same pcap file for reading, this thing happens just once that one time a pcap file is opened and each of its packet is send to both the processes running on CPU1 and CPU2.

Please give me some direction that how can I achoeve this task.

Comment: So you want a third program which reads the PCAP file and somehow sends the packets to the other two programs? Why? As the program you have just reads from the PCAP file there's not going to be any problems.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Will this not cause any problem with respect to memory usage as both processes are opening up the same pcap file.

Comment: I don't know about the PCAP library, but unless the file is extremely big and loaded completely into memory, then no it's not going to be a problem. You don't worry about e.g. your source file being loaded by both your editor and your compiler?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Pcap is a wireshark created file which comprises of network packets. In my case, its size is 2GB. Sorry, I don't get your question. I just compiled my c++ code using g++ and run its executable on both CPUs.

Comment: With the question I mean that it's not unusual that one file is accessed by multiple programs simultaneously. As the file is quite large, you have to check how it's loaded. If it's loaded all at once into memory, then you need to have over 4GB of virtual memory, if the file is loaded piecewise (which would be the natural thing to do with such a type of file) then there's no problem with two programs reading it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg When I checked the memory usage using TOP command of linux .I did not find a large increase in memory on using 1 GB pcap file. Does this indicate that pcap file is loaded piecewise?

Comment: That's one indication, yes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want your processes to do something like this:

1. Open up your pcap file
2. Read some packet out of it
3. Pass that packet onto two threads of your process, each one configured differently

You could have your script read the pcap file and pass binary data on stdin to your c++ program which then processes it.  Or you could use a socket, shared memory a pipe instead of stdin.

I'm assuming that you have access to the code for the program of which you speak.

If not, then it's much more complicated.

Comment: For simplicity, i'd just use stdin or a pipe.  But if I didn't have that option, i'd probably send it on a socket